# Конструктор и логика в js

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в js в нагружать кодом конструктор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно

```
var Constructor = function () {
  // нагружаем как хотим.
  // Объект, созданный при помощи оператора new, доступен через this. 
  // http://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods
}

var instance = new Constructor();
```

Comment: Про new и this. Возможно, стоит упомянуть про паттерн самовызывающегося конструктора, и, соответственно, единственным отличием конструктора от функции становится заглавная буква вначале...


    function Constructor(){
        if ( this instanceof Constructor ) {
            this.property = "блаблабла";
        } else {
            return new Constructor();
        }
    }

Comment: @moron, тогда уже вообще на [Стефана Стоянова](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) переадресовывать надо.